# How to view a data in table

Tags: android, sqlite, select, insert

I inserted `EditText` value in database, Please help me how to get all the data in `table` and show it in a next `Activity`, please help me. I use the following code for inserting:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table pill (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "med VARCHAR, " + "dose1 VARCHAR,"+"dose2 VARCHAR,"+"dose3 VARCHAR);";

// ---insert data into the database---
public long insertData(String med, String dose1,String dose2,String dose3) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(Med, med);
    initialValues.put(Dose1, dose1);
    initialValues.put(Dose2, dose2);
    initialValues.put(Dose3, dose3);


    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

`med`, `dose1`, `dose2`, `dose3` are the values from the `EditText` which is in another class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
db.query()
```

See that

[Query only the first data from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190968/android-sqlite3-query-only-one-datathe-first-from-the-table)